# How to get all attributes names(nested or not) in Servlet Context and iterate if it's a map or list?

Tags: java, loops, servlets, attributes

I've tried to get attributeNames of a ill-maintained context, then use those names with reflection.

Here's some pseudo code for a rough idea.
E.g. I have an ArrayList and a HashMap in the context.

```
enum = getServletContext().getAttributeNames();
for (; enum.hasMoreElements(); ) {
    String name = (String)enum.nextElement();

    // Get the value of the attribute
    Object value = getServletContext().getAttribute(name);

    if (value instanceof HashMap){
      HashMap hmap = (HashMap) value;
      //iterate and print key value pair here
    }else if(value instanceof ArrayList){
      //do arraylist iterate here and print
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question.  Does the code you provided not work?  You may want to use Map and List instead of HashMap and ArrayList.

Comment: @Pace Yea but i'm wonder if it's possible to iterate the nested values of the map and list too.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you basically asking "How to iterate through a hashmap and an arraylist?" How exactly is this related to servlets? That's just basic Java.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's code that will do what you want:

```
Enumeration<?> e = getServletContext().getAttributeNames();
while (e.hasMoreElements())
{
    String name = (String) e.nextElement();

    // Get the value of the attribute
    Object value = getServletContext().getAttribute(name);

    if (value instanceof Map) {
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : ((Map<?, ?>)value).entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
        }
    } else if (value instanceof List) {
        for (Object element : (List)value) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Always favour referring to the abstract interface over concrete implementations. In this case, check for `List` and `Map` (interfaces), rather than `ArrayList` and `HashMap` (specific implementations); consider what will happen if the context hands you a `LinkedList` rather than an `ArrayList`, or a `Map` that's not a `HashMap` - your code would (unnecessarily) explode
2. Use `while (condition)` rather than `for (;condition;)` - it's just ugly
3. If you know the types of your Collections, specify them. For example, web contexts usually give you a `Map<String, Object>`:

so the code could become

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : ((Map<String, Object>)value).entrySet()) {
    String entryKey = entry.getKey();
    Object entryValue = entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: @PAA what's the exact code of yours that's causing the error?